# Desempenho php + mongodb + graficos

Tags: php, desempenho, mongodb

Bom dia povo maravilhoso, sou iniciante em desenvolvimento e tenho uma questão que tem tirado meu sono, estou testando um sistema em php com base de dados mongoDB, no qual é gerado um gráfico com métricas de todos os registros do mongodb (quantidade de registros +- 700K), métricas como, qual o dispositivo usou, gênero, qual link clicou, qual provedor de e-mail entre outros.
isto tem demorado uma eternidade para gerar o gráfico, depois de alguns teste tenho a certeza de que a velocidade é causada pelo php, para obter uma quantidade muito grande de registros.
alguém tem uma ideia de como melhorar este desempenho?
lembrado que os dados são captado apos uma pessoa navegar no meu site(sao pelo menos 100 novos regitros por dia).

Lembrando, ja tentei fazer um cache pelo cron somente com os dados relevantes e mesmo assim a quantidade é gigantesca.

Obrigado!

Comment: Você está lendo e varrendo estes registros a cada requisição para gerar os gráficos? Se sim, o que você pode fazer é, além de armazenar cada clique, montar uma estrutura de dados no seu banco com os dados já consolidados, apenas com o necessário para criar/exibir os gráficos.

Comment: este cache que falei que eu fiz, foi exatamente isso @NewtonWagner, mesmo assim esta estrutura esta ficando gigantesca